# Term for a set of perfect matchings of a complete graph which include every edge exactly once?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, combinations

A [complete graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) is an undirected graph in which all pairs of vertices are connected by an edge. A [perfect matching](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerfectMatching.html) is a selection of edges of the graph which touch every vertex exactly once.

***Is there a name for a set of perfect matchings of a complete graph that select every edge of the graph exactly once?***

---

*Background information for the interested:*

One application of a perfect matching of a complete graph is sports scheduling: if vertices are teams, and edges are games between two teams, then the complete graph is a description of all unique pairings that is possible, and a perfect matching is a set of games that includes each team once. If you have *T* teams, and *T*/2 fields, then the perfect matching describes games that can be played simultaneously in a single round.

If we want to ensure that each team eventually plays every other team, but no pair of teams play each other twice, we want to find a set of perfect matchings that select all edges of the graph exactly once.

For 8 teams, here are two different sets of perfect matchings that cover the space. The first row happened to be hand-crafted (hence the symmetry) while the second row is the result of round-robin scheduling:

[image: two rows of complete graphs with 8 vertices with various edges visually highlighted]

Comment: I think it's called a 1-factorization.

Comment: @GerryMyerson That certainly seems correct. Thank you! Care to post it as an answer?

Comment: Your wish is my command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called a 1-factorization. See for example, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_factorization).